# Use Makefile to create and push dotnet nuget packages

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Make is the current tool used by our devops to control the flow of our builds but we are only leveraging the simplest of use cases, example `all: clean build test` with relevant targets to make that work. We are not making any use of file targets.

I am in the process of trying to extend one of our builds to do the above with an addition package step and then for each generated nuget package push it to our nuget repository.

I am trying to avoid using too much bash and I would like to keep it as much as possible to native Make.

I am much more familiar with Fake and Rake and I don't seem to be able to switch my thinking but I feel like I am close. The following is a cut down version of the Makefile to try and keep things as barebones and as simple as possible to show what I am attempting to do.

What you will see is that the phoney targets work as expected, we get our build and tests to run (excluded in the example) followed by the creation of the nuget packages. It is here I have the issue. I want to run a target for each of the generated nuget packages but cannot seem to make that work.

```
OUT_DIR:=./artifacts
SOLUTION_FILE_PATH:=./src/foo.sln

.PHONY: all
all: clean pack push

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    if [ -d $(OUT_DIR) ]; then rm -Rf $(OUT_DIR); fi

.PHONY: pack
pack:
    # This will generate one or more nupkg files in the output directory
    dotnet pack $(SOLUTION_FILE_PATH) -c Release --output $(OUT_DIR)

# I know this part is not correct but it expresses what I am trying to achieve
.PHONY: push
push: $(OUT_DIR)/%.nupkg
    dotnet push $@
```

I have tried a number of different permutations to get the pattern matching to work but I am find that most of the examples are out there really don't point me in the right direction. Looking for some help to get me past the final hurdle.

** EDIT **

Good question and thanks @beta. If I was to do this manually on the command line you would expect to see this:

```bash
# Creates n number of *.nupkg files in the ./artifacts dir
dotnet pack ./src/foo.sln -c Release --output ./artifacts

# Lets assume it creates 3 nupkg files
dotnet push ./artifacts/foo.package1.nupkg
dotnet push ./artifacts/foo.package2.nupkg
dotnet push ./artifacts/foo.package3.nupkg
```

** Something that works **

I was able to get something to work but I now want to know if this follows the correct convention

```
define dotnetPush
    dotnet nuget push $(1)
endef

.PHONY: push
push:
    $(eval PACKAGES:=$(wildcard $(OUT_DIR)/*.*nupkg))

    $(foreach p,$(PACKAGES),$(call dotnetPush,$(p)))
```

** Resources **

Whilst it didn't help me resolve the issue I have found this [page](https://makefiletutorial.com/) to be immensely helpful.

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with nuget and dotnet, could you spell out exactly how you would do this on the command line, without Make? (Otherwise we must reverse-engineer your intention from a makefile that doesn't work.)

Comment: @Beta - Thanks for calling that out, I have updated and provided additional detail.

Comment: I have updated with something that works but I have heard that some things that appear to work in make may not be "correct" and could cause issues in the future.

Comment: The thing to understand about make is that it is designed to detect whether things are "up to date" or not by comparing timestamps of files on the disk.  If you don't have files on the disk, then you can't use this "are things up to date" feature of make.  If you don't use this feature it's fine, but really you might as well just write a shell script that does what you want since it will do the same thing every time.  A makefile might be helpful if you already use and know make, because it has a few handy features.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `eval` until you are already a makefile guru.  It's needed only for the most advanced makefiles, and is otherwise just confusing.  You can just set this variable globally and it's MUCH less confusing.

You also don't need `call` here: again, this is only needed for more advanced operations.  You can just write the command directly, especially in this case.

```
PUSH = dotnet nuget push

PACKAGES := $(wildcard $(OUT_DIR)/*.*nupkg)

PUSH_PACKAGES := $(addprefix push_,$(PACKAGES))

.PHONY: push
push: $(PUSH_PACKAGES)

push_%:
        $(PUSH) $*
```

Here we create a pattern rule that will build targets starting with `push_` by calling `dotnet nuget push`, and we create a target `push` that lists targets starting with `push_` for each package to be pushed, as a prerequisite.

**ETA**

If you don't know the names of the makefiles until after you run the `pack` command then I recommend this rather than using `eval` etc.:

```
PACK = dotnet pack
PUSH = dotnet nuget push

OUT_DIR := ./artifacts
SOLUTION_FILE_PATH := ./src/foo.sln

.PHONY: all
all: push

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf $(OUT_DIR)

.PHONY: pack
pack: clean
        $(PACK) $(SOLUTION_FILE_PATH) -c Release --output $(OUT_DIR)

.PHONY: push
push: pack
        for pkg in $(OUT_DIR)/*.*nupkg; do $(PUSH) $$pkg || exit 1; done
```

Comment: Thanks Mad, the issue I was seeing (and could have been user error) was that when I did it without eval the wildcard was not picking up any packages and I "assumed" this was because they were not available yet when Make was run. I did the push as a function because it also encapsulates some conditional checks and takes in a second parameter (I removed it for brevity). I will retest using the approach above shortly.

Comment: Well, yes, if the files don't exist when make starts then you can't use this method.  If you don't have any way to figure out what the names of the packages to be uploaded will be when make starts, then you can't use this.

Comment: We "could" provide a list of names but that increases the level of maintenance. If a new packages is added to the solution you have to remember to update the list. The idea is that these scripts are shared, self contained and low maintenance. The "eval" appears to be working. longer term I will be pushing to use something like Fake instead.